# Buttons of the simulator 9800 didn't appear in blackberry

Tags: blackberry-simulator

In my simulator, the buttons of menu, back and the others buttons didn't appear. When I click I find the button but the buttons of simulator are invisible

[image]

Comment: I find the problem. I have View-->Graphics Acceleration--->hight quality. I change it to View-->Graphics Acceleration--->off

Comment: Please add this comment as an answer and mark it as solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the problem. I have View-->Graphics Acceleration--->hight quality. I change it to View-->Graphics Acceleration--->off

Answer (score 0):

Go to "view" in the toolbar and make sure the "LCD Only" is unchecked

Comment: LCD only show just the screen of the simulator but I want to appear the buttoms of the simulator menu, back, close, call...

Comment: no problem. I add as an answer but I can't mark my own answer